# How to fix chmod errors when updating wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, chmod

I recently upgraded from php 5 to 7.2 and my wp site didnt work, service temporarily unavailable error.  So I logged into the backend and WP 5.4 was telling me I needed to check security issues of which I resolved 2 of 3 automatically but 1 could not which is "restrict access to files and folders".  So I tried to update the 2017 theme and when I do so I get a bunch of these(although its the same error):

```
Selected items were updated with errors:
- Unable to update theme 'twentyseventeen_1.7_1_', details: PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/santiapps.com/httpdocs/wordpress_2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 168
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/santiapps.com/httpdocs/wordpress_2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 168
PHP Warning:  chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/santiapps.com/httpdocs/wordpress_2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 168
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/vhosts/santiapps.com/httpdocs/wordpress_2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 168...
```

and near the end it reads:

```
Warning: The update cannot be installed because we will be unable to copy some files. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions. "front-page.php, rtl.css, 404.php...
```

Then in the end it doesnt update of course.  A suggestion by the Wordpress Toolkit on plesk is:
[image: chmod sec suggestions]

Im using filezilla and changing the permissions to those files but I get "operation not permitted".

Answer (score -1):

[SOLVED] (at least for me)

Me too on Cloudways and Digital Ocean.

Just restart the server and error is gone.

Comment: I restarted it but it didnt work.  I still get the 503 error.

Comment: Update the latest WordPress version,